# Uninstall feem completely

Tags: software-center, uninstall, 14.10

I am currently running **Ubuntu 14.10** 64 bit version. I recently installed Feem Wifi direct app from [here](http://www.tryfeem.com/en/download.html).

I had to run the source code from the terminal, **without** root privileges.

Now I am not able to remove the app completely form my laptop as it pops up every time I log in. It opens a webpage that asks me to pay every time it opens.

I tried `sudo apt-get remove feem`, the software centre, and I also tried right clicking on the app from the dash I did not find an uninstall button (which worked for other apps). I also tried in synaptic package manager but Feem didn't have a uninstall button there either. (I am a little unsure if I got this method correct)

Can anyone give me a solution for the same? Preferably a command line one. And also is it possible for me to just remove it from the startup apps? The `startup apllications` that is found in Ubuntu 14.04 is no longer available in 14.10.

Comment: Can you see anything related to feem in `~/.config/autostart`?

Comment: Yes. I found **Feem.desktop**, I changed `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` to `false`. Now it doesn't start up. Thanks. How do I uninstall it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. (As per my answer) you can just delete `~/.config/autostart/Feem.desktop` if you want to uninstall anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the file `~/.config/autostart/Feem.desktop` should prevent it from running on startup. This will not uninstall the application.

To uninstall, you'll have to manually remove the files. You can't use `apt-get` or the software centre, because Feem was not installed by Ubuntu's package manager. I've looked at the installer code, and I can see three locations where it installed to. You can remove all of these. If you like, use the following commands.

```
rm -r ~/bin/Feem
rm -r ~/.local/share/applications/Feem.desktop
rm -r ~/.config/autostart/Feem.desktop
```

If `~/bin` is empty now, you can safely remove this too.

Comment: The `Feem` command itself might not be in `~/bin` if you specified a different target location when you ran the installer.